# How to stop app engine instance with API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-standard

According to the documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch we should be able to stop an app engine instance by changing the serviceStatus to STOPPED.

However, the documentation is ambiguous. Does anyone understand how to stop an app engine instance via the API?

Unclear elements:

1. "Name of the resource to update. Example: apps/myapp/services/default/versions/1." How can you find the "name of the resource"?
2. What should the "updateMask" look like? Is it in json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example how you can **stop/serve** your App Engine version using API, just replace the `PROJECTID`,`SERVICEID` and `VERSIONID`:

```
curl --request PATCH \
"https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/PROJECTID/services/SERVICEID/versions/VERSIONID?updateMask=servingStatus" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"servingStatus":"STOPPED"}' \
  --compressed
```

For you to fully understand how it builds, there's an API Explorer or a panel. It has a title ***"Try this API"*** in the right side of screen, click the box icon to maximize or click this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch?apix=true) to redirect. Fill the required fields:

1. `appsId` - your PROJECT ID.
2. `servicesId` - go to [App Engine > Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services) or execute `gcloud` command: `gcloud app services list` to see your App Engine Services. The default **name** or `servicesID` of your App Engine Services is **default**.
3. `versionsId` - go to [App Engine > Versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) or execute `gcloud` command: `gcloud app versions list` to see the App Engine versions deployed and copy the **VERSION ID** you want to update.
4. `updateMask` - the configuration in App Engine version you want to update, example: **servingStatus** or **instanceClass**

To know more about fields and its definition in API, visit this [table of contents](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions). It will help you a lot how you can configure your App Engine Versions via API.

> NOTE : You cannot stop the App Engine Version if your apps is configured in automatic scaling.

Comment: Why can't you stop the App Engine Version if the your apps is configured in automatic scaling? Where is this documented?

Comment: Because auto-scaled service instances are always running. Here's the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--stop-previous-version).

Comment: So the only way to stop an auto-scaled instance is to delete it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: how to do same w/ gcloud?

Comment: @JDOaktown https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/stop